# How to remove tree lines from JideSoft TreeTable

Tags: java, swing, jide

I have created a tree using TreeTable and now that I have all the data in I want to remove the tree lines that are displayed on the left side. 
As you can see here:

[image]

I want the tree to look like this:

[image]

I tried using these lines of code to remove them:

```
treeTable.setShowGrid(false);
treeTable.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
treeTable.setShowVerticalLines(false);
treeTable.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Is there some table property I am missing that can be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TreeTable.setShowTreeLines()](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/grid/TreeTable.html#setShowTreeLines(boolean)) method:

> We used the same +/- icons used in JTree so it will change based on
>   different LookAndFeels. You can also define your own icons by calling
>   CategorizedTable.setExpandedIcon(javax.swing.Icon) and
>   CategorizedTable.setCollapsedIcon(javax.swing.Icon). The tree lines
>   can be turn on or off using setShowTreeLines(boolean). The line color
>   can be set by setTreeLineColor(java.awt.Color). By default, it will
>   use the JTree's tree line color which is
>   UIManagerLookup.getColor("Tree.hash").